# How to select named tuple/json/map with multiple types from subquery in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm struggling with a query, where I must select a group of named tuples from a subquery result. Sample code looks like this:

```
SELECT 123456 as productId,
       ordersHistory # <- this must be a named tuple like [{'date': '2022-11-10', 'orders': 4}], but now it's only [('2022-11-10', 4)]
FROM products
GLOBAL LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT groupArray(tuple(date, orders)) ordersHistory,
          123456 as productId,
   FROM (
      SELECT date, orders
      FROM orders
      WHERE productId = 123456 AND date BETWEEN '2022-10-10' AND '2022-11-10'
   )
   GROUP BY productId
) orders ON products.productId = orders.productId
```

I've tried maps, but they expect to have a fixed subtype, which is not applicable to my result subset. Cast output format to JSON in subquery is not working either. And I have no clue, how to make named tuples in other ways.

I expect ordersHistory subset of result to be an array of key->value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to workaround this problem.
First of all, we should transform our default tuple to named tuple

```
cast(tuple(date, orders), Tuple(date Date, orders UInt64)) AS namedTuple
```

Named tuples can be cast to JSON

```
namedTuple::JSON as jsonedTuple
```

But groupArray could not work with JSON. So we should transform JSON to some type, which is appliable to group array. Strings are the case

```
toString(jsonedTuple) as stringifiedJson
```

And this stringified JSON could be grouped.

```
groupArray(stringifiedJSON)
```

This transformes into SELECT subquery

```
SELECT groupArray(toString(cast(tuple(date, orders), Tuple(date Date, orders UInt64))::JSON))
```

Yes. This looks awful, but it does it's job and this is only one thing, that I've found to workaround this case.